# Sum of column in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, listview

Currently I need to add the cost of all items in column 3 and display the result in sub total label.

This is the code I have but absolutely nothing happens:

```cs
private void btnLoadCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    decimal gtotal = 0;
    foreach (ListViewItem lstItem in lstCart.Items)
    {
        gtotal += decimal.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[2].Text);
    }
    lblSubTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(gtotal);
}
```

[image: Photo of View List]

Comment: Have you subscribed to that event? Select the `Button` in the designer and double click on it to make sure you have. And you can get the total like: `lblSubTotal = lstCart.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Where(x => decimal.TryParse(x.SubItems(2).Text, null)).Select(x => decimal.Parse(x.SubItems(2).Text)).Sum().ToString("C2");`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to call the `Update` or the `Refresh` method of the parent form after you set the `lblSubTotal.Text` value.

```
    NameOfParentForm.Update();
```

Or

```
    NameOfParentForm.Refresh();
```

Comment: have you tried debugging? do you get any errors or exceptions?